# Unmatched connectors on condenser mic and wireless belt pack - make adapter?

Tags: wireless, bias, condenser-microphone

So I want to buy a Shure Earmic (condenser) which has a mini XLR connector with 4 pins, one of them in the centre. And I want to connect it to an AKG PT40 body pack which has a three pin mini XLR connector. I tried plugging one in directly and it doesn't work. I figure the problem is its how its wired.

Shure pinouts:

```
 1. Shield
 2. Connected to pin 3 via 2.2K resistor
 3. Connected to above resistor via 1uF cap
 4. Not connected
```

PT40 pinouts:

```
 1. Shield
 2. Audio (inphase) and +3.8V
 3. Audio
```

These connection schemas come from the online manuals. My guess is that the bias voltage on the Shure mic is supposed to come in on pin 3 via the cap. Or am I wrong?

What I am thinking of doing is getting a male and female connector and a three inch long piece of shielded cable, and simply making up an adaptor.

Can this logically work?

Comment: Are the pinouts you give exactly the original text or your interpretation? Can you quote/picture and link the originals?

Comment: There are eBay listings for an adapter cable...https://www.ebay.com/itm/261935225922

Comment: Thank you Kevin for looking at this. I googled the pdf manuals. The Shure one had a diagram. But I didn't know how to post pics here. David, that's exactly what I had in mind. Thank you! Pity that item doesn't ship to UK! Couldn't find one this side.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards. A capacitor blocks DC and passes AC (audio), so the bias voltage would pass through pin 2 with the resistor, and the audio would pass through pin 3 with the capacitor.

Since we don't have a precise schematic it's hard to be sure this is exactly right, but **assuming there are no surprises**:

You would want to connect *both* pin 2 and 3 of the Shure pinout to pin 2 of the PT40. If you connect only pin 2 through, then the audio will be attenuated by the resistor; if you connect only pin 3 through then the bias will be missing.

On the PT40 side, assuming the two audio pins are differential (balanced, opposite phases), you will need to connect pin 3 (PT40) *and* pin 1 (PT40 and Shure) together, otherwise the input will be floating and you get no audio through. For best noise rejection, make this junction *at the mic end* of your adapter.

Again, please update your question with schematics or exact original wording if you have them to be sure this is correct advice.